# Hide Text & display message when we click on Button

Tags: shipping, javascript, product-view, out-of-stock

please visit [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html) , you can see there is option to find shipping is available or not for particular zip code : **image1**

[image]

what i want is , once we enter " 110001" in textfield, click on "check" button, it should show as below **image 2** :

[image]

means 1)"Available with 14 sellers" text + 2)"entered zip code" + 3)"change" button.

Now i got solution for 1) & @2) , i need to to display "**change**" button.

**once we click on "change" button, again it should show as in image 1**.

we are using custom [module](https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/tree/master/Magento%20Display%20Shipping%20estimation%20Block%20in%20Product%20view%20page) for displaying shipping charges in Product View page. you can download using [Magento Display shipping estimation block](https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/tree/master/)

**Form.phtml**

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/form.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('postcode')): ?> 
<li class="item"> 

<label for="search"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('') ?></label> 
<div class="search"> 

<input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?>
required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" 
value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}" /> 
</div> 
</li> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
( function($) { 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#estimate_postcode').keydown(function(e){ 

var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input', 
'.shipping-estimation-form select', 
'#product_addtocart_form input', 
'#product_addtocart_form select']); 
var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>'; 
var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true); 
console.log("zipcode onkeypress worked"); 
if (!e) e = window.event; 
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
if (keyCode == '13'){ 
//disable default enter action 
e.preventDefault(); 
console.log("Enter button was pressed"); 
$('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').show(); 
$('#shipping-estimate-results').hide(); 

new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, { 
parameters: parameters, 
onComplete: function() { 
console.log("ajax updater worked"); 
$('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide(); 
$('#shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
$('#unique_id').hide(); 
//$('unique_id').hide(); 
$('estimate_postcode').val()
} 
}); 
}; 
}); 
}); 
} ) ( jQuery ); 

function estimateProductShipping() 
{ 

var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>'; 
var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input', 
'.shipping-estimation-form select', 
'#product_addtocart_form input', 
'#product_addtocart_form select']); 

var validationResult = true; 

// Check the valid input 
if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) { 
return; 
} 

var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true); 

$('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show(); 
$('shipping-estimate-results').hide(); 


new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, { 
parameters: parameters, 
onComplete: function() { 
console.log("ajax updater worked"); 
$('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide(); 
$('shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
// $('#unique_id').hide(); 
$('unique_id').hide(); 
$('estimate_postcode').val()
} 
}); 
} 

//]]> 
</script>
```

complete code of the file : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ebe868508b2c21e9c032

**result.phtml**

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/result.phtml

```
<p><?php echo "Available with 14 sellers at";?>
<?php  $addressInfo = $this->getRequest()->getPost('estimate',array()); ?>
<?php if(isset($addressInfo['postcode']) && $addressInfo['postcode']):?>
<?php echo ' '.$this->htmlEscape($addressInfo['postcode']); ?>
<?php endif;?>
</p>
```

**Edit**

Once i used below answer , than i got my solution for displaying message.

Now i need to display **change** button after message.

Comment: How do you calculate the number of sellers ?

Comment: Thats just the text, for us its not required to calculate any sellers count.

Comment: So the only thing that you need is to hide/show the different sections?

Comment: you are right.... means the some text + entered zip code + `change` button.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add bellow code

**result.phtml**

```
<p style="font-size:20px;"><?php echo "Available with 14 sellers at";?>
<?php  $addressInfo = $this->getRequest()->getPost('estimate',array()); ?>
<?php if(isset($addressInfo['postcode']) && $addressInfo['postcode']):?>
    <?php echo ' '.$this->htmlEscape($addressInfo['postcode']); ?>
<?php endif;?>
    <a style="text-decoration: underline" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeEstimate();"><?php echo $this->__('change')?></a>
</p>
```

**Script:**

> app/design/frontend/default/default/template/webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/form.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
( function($) { 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#estimate_postcode').keydown(function(e){ 

var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input', 
'.shipping-estimation-form select', 
'#product_addtocart_form input', 
'#product_addtocart_form select']); 
var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>'; 
var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true); 
console.log("zipcode onkeypress worked"); 
if (!e) e = window.event; 
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
if (keyCode == '13'){ 
//disable default enter action 
e.preventDefault(); 
console.log("Enter button was pressed"); 
$('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').show(); 
$('#shipping-estimate-results').hide(); 

new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, { 
parameters: parameters, 
onComplete: function() { 
console.log("ajax updater worked"); 
$('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide(); 
$('#shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
$('#unique_id').hide(); 
//$('unique_id').hide(); 
$('estimate_postcode').val()
} 
}); 
}; 
}); 
}); 
} ) ( jQuery ); 

function estimateProductShipping() 
{ 

var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>'; 
var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input', 
'.shipping-estimation-form select', 
'#product_addtocart_form input', 
'#product_addtocart_form select']); 

var validationResult = true; 

// Check the valid input 
if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) { 
return; 
} 

var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true); 

$('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show(); 
$('shipping-estimate-results').hide(); 


new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, { 
parameters: parameters, 
onComplete: function() { 
console.log("ajax updater worked"); 
$('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide(); 
$('shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
// $('#unique_id').hide(); 
$('unique_id').hide(); 
$('estimate_postcode').val()
} 
}); 
}

function changeEstimate(){
    $('unique_id').show();
    $('shipping-estimate-results').hide();
}

/* 

Event.observe('delivery-pincode-change', 'click', function(event){
$('unique_id').show();
$('shipping-estimate-results').hide();               
$('delivery-html').hide();
});

*/


/* 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('check1234').on('click', function(){ 
$('#unique_id').hide(); 
$('#shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
}); 
}); 

*/ 
//]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: i will check & let you know....

Answer (score 1):

Give a unique id to block-shipping-estimate div :

```
...
<div class="block block-shipping-estimate" id="unique_id">
    // first block
</div>

<div id="shipping-estimate-results">
    // result block
</div>
...
```

After that hide this div in your ajax onComplete :

```
...
new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, {
    parameters: parameters,
    onComplete: function() {
       console.log("ajax updater worked");
       $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide();
       $('shipping-estimate-results').show();
       $('#unique_id').hide();                      // hide 
    }    
});
...
```

On click change button run below script :

```
...
$('#shipping-estimate-results').hide();
$('#unique_id').show();
...
```

Comment: i am trying your solution, i will let you know soon.....

Comment: i followed your solution. i tried this : http://pastebin.com/zbwRMUCU , but it didt worked for me.

Comment: Hello @profile 101, Change `<div class="block block-shipping-estimate id=" unique_id"="">` to `<div class="block block-shipping-estimate" id="unique_id">`. After that please try again. And use `jQuery` in place of `$`.

Comment: sorry, i updated code like this, please check : http://pastebin.com/jeMByQ6B

Comment: Either use `jQuery` in place of `$` or define `$` like `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` before use.

Comment: i added like this, can you please check : http://pastebin.com/uFW926Ah

Comment: Why you fire onclick event on check button `$('check1234').on('click', function(){});` ? Comment this event and try.

Comment: i commented it. please check link now : [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37653/discussion-between-profile-101-and-vinaya-maheshwari).